# Best linux distro for workstaton in small business ? Basic purpose run excel,word,pdf and multiple webpages simultaneously?

Tags: networking, free

Looking for commercial workstation OS which legal to use for small business basic purpose is run spreadsheet,word,pdf, and multiple webpages simultaneously each system will be getting 4GB DDR2 RAM (yes they're quit old system with core2duo processor) I've checked linux mint for this and its but still I want your opinion, anyone here using any linux distro for business and is it running with good stability ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're on AskUbuntu site, so you will get only suggestions regarding officially supported flavors of Ubuntu , i.e. your choices are Xubuntu , Lubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Edubuntu, and Mythbuntu. You do sound like you need either Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which are more or less minimalistic and lightweight.

Second, there is no Microsoft Word or Excel on Linux. We have [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) and [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/download/). There is also [WPS office](https://www.wps.com/) , which is more or less similar to Word. You can use however Microsoft Office online.

PDF is openable with [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) but you can't edit them. There's also [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) for reading as well, but I personally use [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html). If you are after the ability to edit the pdfs and don't mind 15$ per month, then you can sign up for [Adobe account](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/edit-pdf-convert-pdf-to-office.html). If you don't want a subscription to Adobe, you can get a commercial PDF editor, [PDF Studio](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/) for 89$. You can also edit PDFs well in LibreOffice Draw.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend you to go for [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) because it is very speedy and has a workstation type of feel. It might a have a classic and rustic feel BUT, It will never compromise when it comes to speedy operations.